# Storing Settings in Android After App Uninstall

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app. This app stores preferences (user settings) relative to its functioning, such as preferred image quality, etc. etc.. And purchases too.

My question is: How to store these settings in Android in a way that they remain persistent even if the application is removed.

Specifically purchases. I want the user to be able to purchase an in-app feature, uninstall the app, and if he reinstalls the app and presses a "Restore Purchases" button, the previously purchased feature will be restored.

I am currently using Android's SharedPreferences to store these settings. I would like some comment on if this will work for my purpose or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer for your specific case is to use the ["managed by user account"](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type) purchase type when you set up in-app billing.

Regarding the general case, your app's `SharedPreferences` are deleted when your app is uninstalled, so no, this will not work.  The only data that is kept around after uninstallation is that stored in a *public* directory in external storage (usually but not always an SD card).  Your app's private directory on external storage is deleted, along with your databases, `SharedPreferences`, etc. during uninstallation.

It would be in poor form (and not very reliable) to use a public area of external storage to try to save user data for this purpose.  The correct solution to the general problem of storing user data across devices or uninstall/reinstall cycles is, as @anoop suggested, to send it to a server.

Comment: Well, in this case there is no need to transfer the data across devices. Just in the same device after uninstall/reinstall.So the "managed by user account" purchase type will remain if the app is installed and reinstalled?

Comment: @VascoPatricio You need to read the documentation for in-app billing.  When you set up in-app billing, you have a choice between "managed" and "unmanaged" -- managed means that when your app is reinstalled, it can ask the in-app billing service which (if any) items this particular user has already purchased.

Answer (score 2):

If you use shared preferences, it will not work. We can't store data permanently using the shared preferences. The best way is using a web service as a backend.

Comment: This is correct in general, but it is not the right thing to do in the case of in-app billing, which is the specific scenario the questioner is dealing with.

Comment: True, but useful feedback nonetheless. Thank you